# How To Debug Apple iOS Crashes - App Store Downloads Only

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have an app on the App Store. It works fine in every simulator and even when I pair it to my device and run it there. I uploaded it to the App Store and did Beta testing through Test Flight and all worked well (but only through iPhone and not iPad - doh). However, when I pushed this live, it now opens momentarily and then crashes when on iPad. I am unable to get any kind of information and cannot debug this, because it works when I go directly from Xcode via wire. I open up organizer in xCode and see no crash logs there. But clearly something is happening. It works perfect on the phones, but only fails on iPads. So my question is, how do I even begin to troubleshoot this if I cannot reproduce this problem? I cannot reproduce it on any simulator, or reproduce it if my iPad is hardwired to my computer. I have tried the latest xCode beta version as well as another version of xCode. So while not a programming question per se, this is a question that might benefit a lot of folks. How would you troubleshoot this? What should be my next steps?

Comment: Can you reproduce the crash on your own iPad if you run the store version or launch via the app icon? If so, you should be able to get the crash log off your own device in XCode->Devices.

Comment: @Columbo - I am able to view those logs! I think you may be onto something here as I can now see the crash logs. These are just plain text files, is there a way to pull them into Xcode so I can find out the exact line as a plain-text stack trace is a bit much? It looks like it is  Thanks so much!
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d

Comment: Ate Bad Food :-)